# Where can I see the output of printf?

Tags: arduino-uno, c

I would like to know where I can see the output when I use the command `printf`. I am programming using the Arduino interface.

### Update

I'll add a few lines of code for better understanding:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your goal is to print something out in your console of the Arduino IDE?

Comment: there is no `main` in Arduino. You have the `setup` for initialization and the `loop` for the continuing loop

Comment: @letsjak there is a `main` in Arduino, but it is hidden http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Where_is_Main_Function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're working with the standard Arduino environment and libraries then `printf()` won't display anything anywhere. The reason is that microcontrollers could be connected to any number of different output/communication devices in any way. `stdio` would have no idea how or where to send the data.

The most common approach to outputting text from an Arduino (particularly during development) is to send it to the primary UART port using [`Serial.begin()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin) and [`Serial.print()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print). If the Arduino is connected to your computer via USB then the Arduino IDE's serial monitor should display the result.

If you *really* want to use `printf()` though then it is possible to make it work (or implement similar functionality). A full explanation is on this page:

- http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Printf

Answer (score 2):

In `setup()`, start serial and choose your speed:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

Wherever you want to write to serial:

```
Serial.write("write this");
```

Wherever you want a newline:

```
Serial.println();
```

### example

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.write("Hello World");

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: my question is actually where am I printing if I don't define `Serial` in `void setup()` and just type `printf` in `void loop()`?

Comment: @ironzionlion if you read the printf documentation.. you will find it...

Comment: @ironzionlion it's an LCD... tadaaaaaaa http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Printf